# Why does my program give a '.class' expected error?

Tags: java

I have no idea where the problem is in my code.

Shouldn't it keep looping while `int a` is less than `int b`?

Any help would be appreciated because I'm trying to learn and this has me seriously confused.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Keep prompting the user until the input is correct
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter two positive integers, the first smaller than the second.");
            System.out.print("First: ");
            int a = in.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Second: ");
            int b = in.nextInt();
        }while(int a > int b);
        // Only print this when the input is correct
        System.out.println("You entered " + a + " and " + b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please 1) show the full error message. 2) show how you compile and call this code. 3) don't post your entire question as a block quote as that is not what this option is for and detracts from your question.

Comment: Please fix compile error first...

Answer (score 1):

You received an error because you're declaring `a` and `b` in the while so they aren't the same as those in your do block.

To have them in scope of both the `do` and `while` you'd have to have them declared outside the do-while, but in the main method (like so):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoNumbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a;
    int b;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Keep prompting the user until the input is correct
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter two positive integers, the first smaller than the second.");
        System.out.print("First: ");
        a = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Second: ");
        b = in.nextInt();
    }
    while(a > b);
    // Only print this when the input is correct
    System.out.println("You entered " + a + " and " + b);
}
}
```

Comment: Method local variable would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring those variables in the while so they aren't the same as those in your do block. Additionally, that shouldn't compile so I'm not sure how it would loop at all.

To have them in scope to the while you'd have to have them declared outside the do.

Comment: is there a way i can make them the same?